# SQL: Getting SQL to "count" a number of actions performed within the database

Tags: sql

I would like to perform a query where I can get SQL to "tally" up a number of actions performed. In this case I have an EmpNo which would be linked to an AcctNo that would be associated with a number of Orders.

What would be a way to approach this?

Sorry, about that, I've been thinking on this awhile and was honestly not sure how to set it up. But insofar

```
SELECT EmpNo, LastName, CustomerOrder.OrderNo AS 'Orders Handled"
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Customer
      ON Employee.EmpNo = Customer.AcctRepNo
ORDER BY LastName
```

Comment: Please show your DB structure and query so far

Comment: -1 Would you like some bear with that?!! give us some code, it may help to realize what is the situation man.

Comment: what do you mean by  "tally" up a number of actions performed, Do you want number of orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this kind of query using COUNT() and GROUP BY:

```
 SELECT EmpNo, LastName, COUNT(OrderNo) AS OrdersHandled
 FROM Employee INNER JOIN Customer ON Employee.EmpNo = Customer.AcctRepNo
 INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustNo = Customer.CustNo
 GROUP BY EmpNo, LastName
```

You may need to qualify the column names in the SELECT if both `Customer` and `Employee` have `LastName` columns.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. Sorry, I am very new to SQL. The COUNT command, I was thinking of some overly complicated way involving arithmetic commands.

Comment: You should *always* prefix the column names with the table (alias) - not only if they are ambigous. It makes your SQL more readable and more robust against changes.